# Marking up HTML code with microdata when there are multiple products on a page

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I have a page which compares 4 products at a time in **parallel tabular form** i.e. It mentions features of each of them one after another. Here is a [sample page](http://compare-mobiles.buyhatke.com/Samsung-I9505-Galaxy-S4-Vs-HTC-One-Vs-Apple-iPhone-5-Vs-Sony-Xperia-Z) .

I wish to tag these features so that it becomes easier for search engines to interpret. However, in all the examples given [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146862), you have to mention all the features of a product at a time in a div. This causes a problem for my case, where I mention the features of product together.

A typical example as given goes like this :-

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <span itemprop="name">Blend-O-Matic</span>
  <span itemprop="price">$19.95</span>
</div>
```

However, I would like it to be in this way :-

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      <span itemprop="name">Blend-O-Matic</span> // Item 1
    </div>
   <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      <span itemprop="name">Blend-O-Matic2</span> // Item 2
    </div>
```

Further followed by :-

```
 <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      <span itemprop="price">$19.95</span> // Item 1
    </div>
   <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      <span itemprop="price">$21.95</span> // Item 2
    </div>
```

So, in nutshell, is there a way so that I can tag an item with some code and then use it to refer to other details of that item ?

Please comment if I am unclear in asking my doubt !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `itemref`:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemref="item1_price">
    <span itemprop="name">Blend-O-Matic</span>
</div>

<div id="item1_price">
    <span itemprop="price">$19.95</span>
</div>
```

See results from Google Structured Data Testing Tool [here](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=&html=%3Cdiv+itemscope+itemtype%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FOffer%22+itemref%3D%22item1_price%22%3E%0D%0A++++%3Cspan+itemprop%3D%22name%22%3EBlend-O-Matic%3C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cdiv+id%3D%22item1_price%22%3E%0D%0A++++%3Cspan+itemprop%3D%22price%22%3E%2419.95%3C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E)

Comment: I have this: `<div class="prices" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemref="stock-status">`. I tried linking it to "availability" like this: `<p id="stock-status"><link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" /></p>` and linke this: `<div id="stock-status"><link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" /></div>` But availability is being interpreted as part of the parent `Product` schema, not Offer. So I'm getting `Error: Page contains property "availability" which is not part of the schema.`

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at this for SERP. It shows how to have multiple products in a "ItemList"

http://scottgale.com/schema-org-markup-serp/2013/03/17/

Hth

**PS: This works without error or issue on the Google Structured Data testing tool over at http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets**

Answer (score 1):

But)))
If to be more realistic - You always have WebPage itemtype yes?
So if you have it we have about this:

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
      <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemref="item1_price">
           <span itemprop="name">Blend-O-Matic</span>
      </div>

      <div id="item1_price">
           <span itemprop="price">$19.95</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

See the [google result](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=&html=%3Cdiv+itemscope%3D%22%22+itemtype%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FWebPage%22%3E%0D%0A++++++++++%3Cdiv+itemscope+itemtype%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FOffer%22+itemref%3D%22item1_price%22%3E%0D%0A+++++++++++++++%3Cspan+itemprop%3D%22name%22%3EBlend-O-Matic%3C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A++++++++++%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++++++++%3Cdiv+id%3D%22item1_price%22%3E%0D%0A+++++++++++++++%3Cspan+itemprop%3D%22price%22%3E%2419.95%3C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A++++++++++%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A++++%3C%2Fdiv%3E)
And we have a mistake. If we add the same itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" we will have one full offer and one duplicate with only price. Code:

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
      <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemref="item1_price">
           <span itemprop="name">Blend-O-Matic</span>
      </div>

      <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
           <span id="item1_price" itemprop="price">$19.95</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

[Google result](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=&html=%20%3Cdiv%20itemscope=%22%22%20itemtype=%22http://schema.org/WebPage%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20itemscope=%22%22%20itemtype=%22http://schema.org/Offer%22%20itemref=%22item1_price%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20itemprop=%22name%22%3EBlend-O-Matic%3C/span%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20itemscope=%22%22%20itemtype=%22http://schema.org/Offer%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20id=%22item1_price%22%20itemprop=%22price%22%3E%2419.95%3C/span%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E)

So we need a different way as I understand, am I right?

Comment: I think you have not got the question correctly. You would need itemref attribute if the entire details of a product comes together. itemref is just used to tag a product and then assign some values later on. See here http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fcompare-mobiles.buyhatke.com%2FNokia-Lumia-920-Vs-Nokia-Lumia-822-Vs-Nokia-Lumia-810-Vs-Nokia-Lumia-820&html=

Comment: Wow!! ))) What's this itemprop="coresAvailable"? You add your own class? Or used schema extension?

Comment: They say that you can always add your class if its not there. Google will probably understand that. http://schema.org/docs/extension.html